# CEFsharp not loading url correctly C#

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

using CEFsharp in winform solution, and facing an odd error, trying to load google trends url and it gives me 429 error don't know why, when I use chrome/firefox for the same link it work in perfect way 
here is snippet of code:

```
 GoogleTrendsForm NewGoogleTrendsForm = new GoogleTrendsForm("Google");
            NewGoogleTrendsForm.ShowDialog();

____________________________________________________________________

     public GoogleTrendsForm(string keyword)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChromium();

            //https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=Google&geo=US
            chromeBrowser.Load("https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=" + keyword + "&geo=US");

        }
```

Comment: Doubt this has anything to do with `CefSharp.` Open `Chrome`, open a new `Incognito tab`, load the trends url.

Comment: `The HTTP 429 Too Many Requests response status code indicates the user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting").`

Comment: when I used Incognito , it gives me the error , is there any way to run CEFsharp as normal browser not Incognito  ?

Comment: @amaitland when I used Incognito , it gives me the error , is there any way to run CEFsharp as normal browser not Incognito ? – J. Mark 21 secs ago   edit

Comment: Specify a `CachePath` and cookies etc will be persisted. I doubt this will solve your problem. Google `google trends too many requests` and you'll see there are plenty of others seeing similar problems.

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/search?q=cachepath&unscoped_q=cachepath

Comment: tried that, didn't go well ! sounds that I am gonna use Geckofx instead, but I prefer CEF !

Comment: Tried what exactly? What does didn't go well mean? I expect you'll have problems unless your logged into a google account.